# My Cortana Skill doesn't work perfectly

Tags: botframework, cortana-skills-kit

I wrote a chatbot in Bot Framework builder for this Cortana. Sometimes I get **"I can't connect at the moment. Please try again in a little bit."** when I use it, but sometimes it worked with the same word.

Is anyone know what is the real reason for this message? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code is hard to know. It could be related to your internet connection or with your bot's code.

First, you should check if in the Bot Framework portal there are errors reported under the Cortana channel in your Bot.

Also, you should enable debugging in your Cortana Skill just in case something is going on with your code. Check the [Testing & Debugging Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/testing/testing-and-debugging) documentation article from Cortana Skills.